# SQL Query Not being executed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get a default query to implement upon page load but I get: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM artist, cakes WHERE artist.artist_id = cakes.artist_id ORDER BY artist.ar' at line 2

I'm quite new to SQL and my lecturer couldn't help saying it is too complex but offered no further explanation so I thought it best to ask here.

The query in question:

```
    $q = "SELECT artist.artist_id, 
          CONCAT_WS(' ', artist_name) AS artist,
          cake_name,
          price,
          description,
          cake_id,
          FROM artist, cakes 
          WHERE artist.artist_id = cakes.artist_id
          ORDER BY artist.artist_name ASC,
          cakes.cake_name ASC";  //getting the cakes to display in ascending order of artist then cake name
```

Any help or insight where I've gone wrong would be gratefully received, thanks in advance!

Comment: remove **,** in front of your **FROM**

Comment: It helps a lot to type out your queries with linebreaks and indentation, to spot syntax errors.  Also, wherever MySQL points to in the error message (_near 'FROM_), look to the character that occurs right before. That's where your error will almost always be.

Comment: Cheers Michael, will do that in future, wasn't too sure what the error was saying as it wasn't on line 2. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: If your lecturer thinks this query is too complex, you may want to find a new lecturer...

Comment: I would love a different lecturer, but hey he thinks DB connection information should be in HTML/PHP files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got an extra comma after cake_id.

```
cake_id FROM artist,
```

Comment: You're a star. Sorry about the delay the FTP wouldn't connect so couldn't test, will mark this as answered correctly in ten minutes! What do I pay my lecturer for. . . Haha, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra comma at the end of your `SELECT` clause, just before the `FROM` clause:

```
AS artist, cake_name, price, description, cake_id, FROM artist, cakes
```

You can more easily spot such errors by formatting your code in a more readable manner.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
  artist.artist_id,
  CONCAT_WS(' ', artist_name) AS artist,
  cake_name,
  price,
  description,
  cake_id, -- more obvious error
FROM
  artist,
  cakes 
WHERE
  artist.artist_id = cakes.artist_id
ORDER BY
  artist.artist_name ASC,
  cakes.cake_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "SELECT artist.artist_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', artist_name) 
AS artist, cake_name, price, description, cake_id, FROM artist, cakes 
                                                 ^---REMOVE THIS DIRTY COMMA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   artist.artist_id
        ,CONCAT_WS(' ', artist_name) AS artist
                ,cake_name
        ,price
        ,description
        ,cake_id
        , FROM artist, cakes 
WHERE artist.artist_id = cakes.artist_id ORDER BY artist.artist_name ASC,
cakes.cake_name ASC
```

You have a comma in front of the FROM.